# Responding to out-of-scope multicast

Tags: .net, c, sockets, ip, multicast

How to respond to a multicast udp message sent from a different ip range? 
I have a scenario in which I've implemented a simple SLP server (http://www.openslp.org/doc/rfc/rfc2608.txt) on a small device and a simple SLP client on a PC. 
The device has an ip. Eg. 10.0.0.50 
The PC however has several ips. Eg. 10.0.0.70, 192.168.1.70, 172.19.1.70 
The PC also have several network adapters, that each have several ips. (Never mind that.)

From the PC I send out an udp message to the slp multicast group:

```
System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient client = new System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient(new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 0));
client.Send(m_tx_buffer, encoded, SLPMULTICASTGROUP, SLPPORT);
```

The .net UdpClient will select a random ip to attach to the udp message.
The device will recieve the udp message and send back a unicast message to the given sender ip. Like so:

```
int mysock;
struct sockaddr_in myaddr, cliaddr;
char msgbuf[MAXLEN];
socklen_t clilen;
int msglen;
mysock = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
myaddr.sin_port = htons( S_PORT );
myaddr.sin_addr = htonl( INADDR_ANY );
bind(mysock, &myaddr, sizeof(myaddr));
while (1) {
   len=sizeof(cliaddr);
   msglen=recvfrom(mysock,msgbuf,MAXLEN,0,cliaddr,&clilen);
   sendto(mysock,msgbuf,msglen,0,cliaddr,clilen);
}
```

Problem is if the .net chooses eg. ip 192.168.1.70. The device will respond to this. And it doesn't seem to get through to the PC. (The PC and the device share the 10.0.0.x range.)

Is it supposed to get through? (I've verified with Wireshark that the message doesn't arrive on the PC. And I've verified with my jtag that the device sends out a message.)


To solve this I could make the PC enumerate all ips and send out several udp messages. But this has somewhat bad performance and it risks flooding the poor devices. (The device will recieve all the messages and respond accordingly. It's the PC that doesn't recieve the responses.)


Is it my device (it's a small RTOS btw.) that has a flawed transmisson?

Or is there some way to solve this problem, without flooding my small devices?

Comment: I don't see your device joining the multicast group. Have you omitted that part from the snippet?

Comment: Yes, the snippet was just a nice self contained sample. The real code also joins a multicast group (and has a lot of encoding/decoding.)

Comment: Please post `netstat -rn` and `ifconfig` (or its equivalent) from your RTOS device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your device to be able to send to IP addresses that aren't on the directly attached subnet, you'll have to give it routes for those IP addresses.

You might be able to simply give it a default route through the PC (ie. a default route with a gateway of `10.0.0.70`).

Comment: Assuming that I could change the gateway (which currently is supplied by DHCP) there's still a problem with the "what". The device (recvfrom) will only see the PC as eg. 192.168.1.70. It cannot know that it is in fact 10.0.0.70 or that it should change the gateway to this?

Comment: @Illi You don't need to change the gateway. You only have to say "packets to 192.168.1.70/32 are routed via 10.0.0.70" (`ip r a 192.168.1.70/32 via 10.0.0.70`)

Comment: @Illi Of course, the best solution would be to change the .net application to just use the correct interface or bind the socket to the correct source address.

Comment: @Illishar: It's OK for it to reply to `192.168.1.70`, because that *is* one of the PCs IP addresses.  The only problem is that the IP stack on the device needs to know that to get to `192.168.1.70` it has to go via `10.0.0.70`, which is what the route is for (a specific one if it already has a default route through a different machine).

Comment: The device wouldn't know that it should route to 10.0.0.70. But suppose I routed 192.168.1.70/32 via 10.0.0.1? (That's the actually gateway.) I assumed it already worked like that, but I could give it a try.

Comment: @Illishar: That will work if the gateway knows how to get to `192.168.1.70`.

Comment: Yes, a few potential solutions: 1. Flood the devices. 2. Let the PC (User) define on which interface he wants to search or 3. experiment with the device routing table.